# Variable scope when writing meteor package

Tags: javascript, scope, meteor

When I was writing a js file in a meteor package, I had following codes:

```
A = 1;
console.log(A);
console.log(window.A);
```

I'm wondering why the first console.log prints 1 but the second prints undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the `bundler` is inteligent enough to parse your package source code looking for **global variables**. After all, the (generated) code of your package (i.e. the one that actually gets loaded to the browser) is preceeded by something like:

```
/* Package-scope variables */
var A;
```

which should explaing everything ;)

If you really want to export your variables to be available outside your package do as @sbking told you, so in `package.js` write:

```
// was Package.on_use in older Meteor versions
Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.export('A');
});
```

### Edit

One thing to keep in mind is that when you put `use strict` statement at the beginning of your file, Meteor will no longer detect the implicit global variables unless their explicitly exported with `api.export`. So this is only problematic when you want to have private global variables across your package code.

Note that when **strict mode** is active and those variables are not put into the package "preamble", trying to assing value to an undefined variable will result in runtime error, so this is in fact a deal breaker. Look [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5343#issuecomment-146030175) for more details about this problem.

A simple workaround is to put all the private globals in a single file, with no `use strict` statement at the beginning:

```
// globals.js
// no "use strict" statement here ...
MyPrivateVariable1 = null;
MyPrivateVariable2 = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Meteor namespaces package variables.](http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing) To export a package variable you need to use `api.export` in your `package.js` file. See an example here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/email/package.js